# how to search trough a file for a particular word

Tags: bash

For example I have a file with words

```
jogging:1 swimming:1 running:1 breathing:1
riding:1  walking:1  jogging:2  seeing:1
seeking:1 looking:1 staring:1 practicing:1
```

And I want to search the whole file for that word if possible with a loop(for or while) and that word can appear multiple times
So it would return this if I needed to search for the word jogging

```
jogging:1
jogging:2
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$ grep -oP 'jogging:\d+' file
jogging:1
jogging:2
```

or with an old `grep`:

```
$ grep -o 'jogging:[0-9]\+' file
jogging:1
jogging:2
```

If you insist to use a `for loop`:

```
set -f

for word in $(< file); do
    [[ $word =~ jogging:[0-9]+ ]] && echo "$word"
done
```

I take advantage of *word splitting* here

Comment: Word splitting yes, but also filename expansion. You might consider [`set -f`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin)